# Passing the event via an attached event listener

Tags: javascript

After spending so much time in jQuery, I'm rusty on my old fashioned JS...

The question: When attaching an event to an object that you want to trigger a function, how do you pass the event to said function?

Example function:

```
myFunction(e){
    ...
}
```

Example event attachment:

```
document.getElementById('blargh').onkeypress = function(){myfunction([what do I put here to pass the event?])};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the handler accept a parameter, say `event`, and pass it to your function:

```
document.getElementById('blargh').onkeypress = function(event){myfunction(event)};
```

The event handler always gets the current event passed as parameter... in the W3C model.

For IE you have to get the parameter via `window.event`. Thus, in the function you can write something like:

```
function(event) { event = event || window.event; myfuntion(event);}
```

Comment: That was fast! So fast, that I can't accept it as an answer yet. Thanks! (I'll be back to accept it...)

Answer (score 1):

you can try using `arguments`. This variable gets automatically populated in the local scope. It is an array of all the arguments that was passed into the function. If you pass `arguments` on to your `myfunction`, everything that was passed into the even handler will be passed as an array to `myfunction`.

```
document.getElementById('blargh').onkeypress = function(){myfunction(arguments)};

function myfunction(args)
{
   alert(args[0]);
}
```